# How to display what I drew on a custom View's canvas only at certain times?

Tags: android

So I have a custom `View` which has a `BitmapDrawable` as its background which I draw to:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    draw_game_map(); 
    draw_player();
    draw_overlay_with_circle();
}
```

(each of these methods just draws bitmap(s))

Now I'm calling `View.draw(Canvas)` 60 times per second and it works fine, except I want to have something like this:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //From this point, don't show what I'm about to draw
    draw_game_map();
    draw_player();
    draw_overlay_with_circle();
    //Show what I just drew
}
```

Any code I can add to only display the changes made only after I'm done drawing, rather than during?